# Masking Data Unequal to Another Set of Data and Storing Results

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Does anyone know how to amend the "changes" dataframe to only evaluate cells that are true?  I want to send only those items to changes in df2 from df1 to the changes dataframe.  This replaces all cells and I can't use "mask" by itself since it's multidimensional.  Thanks!

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np 
df1=pd.DataFrame({'Col1' : ['blue', 2, 3, 4], 'Col2' : [90, 99, 3, 97], 'Col3' : [11, 12, 13, 14]})
df2=pd.DataFrame({'Col1' : ['blue', 2, 6], 'Col2' : [90, 99, 99], 'Col3' : [11, 12, 13]})
mask=df2.ne(df1)
#Line in question    
changes=(df1.loc[mask.index].astype(str) + ' changed to: ***' + df2.loc[mask.index].astype(str)).fillna(df2.astype(str))
```

I want the output to look like:

```
Col1    Col2    Col3
0   blue    90  11
1   2   99  12
2   3 changed to: ***6  3 changed to: ***99.0   13
3   4 changed to: ***nan    97 changed to: ***nan   14 changed to: ***nan
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IIUC, you can use `where` with the `other` parameter [see docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.where.html#pandas-dataframe-where):

```
df1.where(df1.eq(df2), changes)
```

Output:

```
                   Col1                   Col2                   Col3
0                  blue                     90                     11
1                     2                     99                     12
2    3 changed to: ***6  3 changed to: ***99.0                     13
3  4 changed to: ***nan  97 changed to: ***nan  14 changed to: ***nan
```

Answer (score 2):

Similar approach to Scott Boston's method. (Credit to him!) You can use `where`'s variant: `mask`.

```
df1.mask(df1.ne(df2), df2)
```

This tell you that, whenever `df1.ne(df2)` is `True`, fill in values from `df2`; otherwise, do not change.

```
    Col1    Col2    Col3
0   blue    90.0    11.0
1   2       99.0    12.0
2   6       99.0    13.0
3   NaN     NaN     NaN
```

Comment: I may end up using this method in my second project!  Thanks for the idea!

Comment: @TylerRussell no problem. Just to introduce this method to you.